# How many integer solutions are there on an $n$ dimensional hypersphere of radius $\sqrt{r}$ centered at the origin?

Tags: diophantine-equations, theta-functions

Let $\phi(n,r)$ be the number of integer solutions of 
$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i^2=r$.

Then $\phi(2,r)=4\sum\limits_{d|r}\chi(d)$ where $\chi (x)=sin(\frac{\pi x}{2})=\cases{ 1\text{ when }x\cong 1 \text{ mod }4 \\ -1 \text{ when }x\cong 3 \text{ mod }4 \\ 0 \text{ when } 2|x }$

And $\phi(4,r)=8\sum\limits_{d|r}\psi(d)$ where $\psi (x)=\cases{x \text{ when }x\ncong 0 \text{ mod }4 \\ 0 \text{ when }x\cong 0 \text{ mod }4 }$

I am asking for leads on theta series. What else is known about $\phi(n,r)$? Is there an explicit formula for other $n$? Is there an explicit formula in $n$ and $r$?

Comment: You might try Grosswald, Representations of Integers as Sums of Squares.

Comment: short piece by Ken Ono http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~ono/publications-cv/pdfs/066.pdf

Comment: https://www.springer.com/us/book/9781461385684

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22569/is-there-a-nice-expression-for-the-number-of-lattice-points-on-a-sphere?rq=1

Comment: [here's](https://people.math.carleton.ca/~williams/papers/pdf/278.pdf) $n=6$

Comment: [n=12](https://people.math.carleton.ca/~williams/papers/pdf/321.pdf)

Comment: I cannot tell whether you know this: there is a book-length article on this by Stephen C. Milne, published in 2002 in The Ramanujan Journal. That is, volume 6, number 1, March 2002. link https://books.google.com/books?id=WsrSBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA5&lpg=PA5&dq=steve+milne+ramanujan+journal&source=bl&ots=KapN-_nJye&sig=ACfU3U3yFgI2Na8iDfEpb9RNAk58KnxUGA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiIjs-lhsXkAhViJTQIHXyiA6gQ6AEwA3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=steve%20milne%20ramanujan%20journal&f=false

Comment: Thanks. I found formulae for $n=4,8,12, \dots, 44$ [here.](https://people.math.carleton.ca/~williams/papers/pdf/335.pdf) which appear on page 44.

Comment: And a form of [n=14](https://people.math.carleton.ca/~williams/papers/pdf/346.pdf) appears on page 95.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to WillJagy for the helpful comments. The [wolfram article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html) on this is nice. Particularly, formula (37) of that article is pretty impressive in light of how complicated this gets in the case $n=3$. For this case check out the [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3596/is-there-a-simple-way-to-compute-the-number-of-ways-to-write-a-positive-integer-a) for a summary and then this [Bateman](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1990859?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) paper for the whole story.

[The piece by Ono](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~ono/publications-cv/pdfs/066.pdf) is pretty rewarding and has a lot of good leads. I found that we don't have an explicit formula for $\phi(n,r)$ but we do have a formula for a specific class of hyperspheres. Namely, when the dimension $n$ is given by $(2s)^2$ or $(2s+1)^2-1$ we know how many solutions can be given for all $r$. These appear as corollary 2 of that paper but they are not easily recreated in a contained way.

Here some more easily contained formulae:

$$ \phi(6,r)=16\sum_{d|r} \bigg( \frac{ -4}{r/d} \bigg)d^2-4\sum_{d|r}\bigg( \frac{ -4}{d} \bigg)d^2 $$

Where above appears [Legendre-Jacobi-Kronecker symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_symbol).

$$\phi(8,r)=16\sum_{d|r}(-1)^{d+r}d^3$$

Also appears this quote

"Therefore, the problem of computing non-trivial formulas for $r(s; n)$ [ which is $\phi(n,s)$ in the notation of this SE post] remains since the coefficients of cusp forms, although small, rarely have simple descriptions." [Ono]

Speaking of computability, I will shamelessly plug [a generalization of this S.E. question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/40990/is-satisfying-sum-i-1nx-iy-i-r-np-complete). Instead of asking "how many solutions are there to $\sum_{i=1}^n{x_i^2}=r$?" We can ask "how many solutions are there to $\sum_{i=1}^n{x_i^{y_i}}=r$?"

Comment: $\sum_{r=0}^\infty \phi(n,r)$ can be used to create a limit for the volume of the $n$th dimensional hypersphere. Here is an example for $n=8$. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/twvtr8if86

Comment: Here is a proof of the 8 dimensional [case](http://people.math.carleton.ca/~williams/papers/pdf/236.pdf)

Comment: The [Bateman](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1951-071-01/S0002-9947-1951-0042438-4/S0002-9947-1951-0042438-4.pdf) paper without a paywall. The relevant theorem is Theorem B.