# Exploiting a Diophantine approximation of $\pi^4$ into giving a series of rationals for $\pi^4$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analytic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, sums-of-squares, diophantine-approximation

A note about this question: The original question asked seems likely impossible so I am really asking if we can exploit the technique below into giving us a 'nice' form for $\pi^4$. By nice form I mean an explicitly defined series of rationals.

**A little explanation of the the technique.**

The technique I use below I reference quite a bit on this site and therefore am putting a nice explanatory picture. The technique is a type of "Diophantine Approximation" I suppose. I don't know if the technique goes by a special name.

We are going to count the number integer solutions along some Diophantine equation $P(x,y)=n$. If let $\phi_n$ denote the number of solutions in $\mathbb{Z}$ to $P(x,y)=n$ then we may argue (under some conditions) that $\sum_{n=1}^N \phi_n$ approximates the area of the interior of $P(x,y)=N$. Let me give a concrete example. Let $P(x,y)=|x|^3+|y|^3$.

[image]

The actual area in the interior of $|x|^3+|y|^3=72$ is given by $\frac{72\Gamma(1/3)^3}{4\sqrt{3}\pi} \approx 63.59899501$ and this is weakly approximated by $69$ which is the total number of integers which are on some solution of $|x|^3+|y|^3=n$ as $n$ varies from $0$ to $72$. Approximating this area as the number of integer solutions should improve as a we let $n$ grow large.

**Specific Question**

Let $R$ be a whole number. Is it possible for any whole number $c>0$ that there is a nicer form for $\sum_{r=1}^{R^c}\sum_{d|r}(-1)^{r+d} d^3$? I can hope that we can just evaluate this sum but in lieu of that maybe something cheaper computationally.  Taking $c=1$ we can examine:
$$f(x)=\sum_{r=1}^{x}\sum_{d|r}(-1)^{r+d} d^3$$
[Here is a table of the first 100 values](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/7cwz90lte1) of this function $f$. This function must grow $O(x^4)$ for reasons which should be clear after reading the exposition. TLDR: $f(x)/x^4$ limits to $\frac{\pi^4}{384}$ as $x$ gets large.

**Edit 1:** After thinking about this specific question I realized it's somewhat an unreasonable ask... In someways this specific question is tantamount to asking [the Gauss circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem) but in 8 dimensions and not 2. It's seems that this problem doesn't have an answer for $2$-d case and it's not likely any easier as we increase the dimension. What I am really after is if we can exploit this summation to arrive at an expression for $\pi^4$ which isn't a divisor sum the same way we can do this in the 2 dimensional case. Full apologies: This is really a different question than the original query but considering the original query is likely impossible...

**Exposition.**

Let $\phi_n(r)$ denote [the number of integer solutions to the $n$-dimensional hypersphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2810894/how-many-integer-solutions-are-there-on-an-n-dimensional-hypersphere-of-radius/2818745#2818745) $r=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$.

**The 2-dimensional case.**

Then discovering $\phi_2(r)=4 \sum_{d|r} \sin(\frac{\pi}{2}d)$ allows us to find a [formula for $\pi$](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NaL_Cb42WyY). Namely, [Leibniz's formula for $\pi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80). Considering that the sum of number of integer solutions for each $r$ from $1$ to $R^2$ should approximate the volume of a sphere (which for this special case $n=2$ goes by the special name 'circle') with radius $R$ we arrive at:

$$\pi R^2 \approx\sum_{r=1}^{R^2}\phi_2(r)$$ and after dividing both sides by $4R^2$ and unpacking our definitions we arrive $$\frac{\pi}{4}=\lim_{R\to\infty} \frac{1}{R^2}\sum_{r=1}^{R^2}\sum_{d|r}\sin \Big(\frac{\pi}{2}d \Big)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{1}{n}\sin\Big(\frac{\pi}{2}n \Big)}=1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+ \dots $$

The second equality is sometimes referred to as a [dirichlet convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution) (I think). And it's this step that I can't seem to be able to take in $8$-dimensional case.

**I will skip the 4-dimensional case.**

But indeed, examining the 4 dimensional case we can achieve $\zeta(2)=\pi^2/6$. This can be found in the last proof in [R. Chapman's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/226/robin-chapman)  [compilation of proofs](http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/rjchapma/etc/zeta2.pdf) of the Basel problem. [MSE has it's own compilation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1k2-basel-pro) of these by the way.

So now that we've seen the development for a $2$ and $4$ dimensional sphere:

**What's the development for 8-dimensional sphere?**

Note that the ${\phi_8(r)= 16\sum_{d|r} (-1)^{r+d}d^3}$ which gives a way of approximate the volume of an $8$-dimensional hypersphere:

$$\frac{1}{24}\pi^4 R^8 \approx \sum_{r=1}^{R^2}\phi_8(r)$$

We divide both sides by $16R^8$ to arrive at

$$\frac{\pi^4}{384}= \lim_{R\to\infty} \frac{1}{R^8}\sum_{r=1}^{R^2} \sum_{d|r} (-1)^{r+d}d^3$$

In fact! It looks to me like for any whole number $c$,

$$\frac{\pi^4}{384}= \lim_{R\to\infty} \frac{1}{R^{4c}}\sum_{r=1}^{R^c} \sum_{d|r} (-1)^{r+d}d^3$$

This does provide a nice sequence which converges to $\pi^4/384$. Letting $c=1$ this sequence's rate of convergence is pretty atrocious.

$$1,\frac{8}{16},\frac{36}{81},\frac{107}{256},\frac{233}{625},\dots $$

The printed numbers are all accurate to ... zero decimal places... it should converge nonetheless.

but taking $c$ larger we arrive at this number much faster. For $c=2$,

$$1,\frac{107}{256},\frac{2113}{6561},\frac{19128}{65536}, \dots $$

Only the last number printed is accurate to the first decimal of $\pi^4/384$.

Can I see anything else here? Is there a closed form for this

$$\sum_{r=1}^{R^c}\sum_{d|r}(-1)^{r+d} d^3$$

Sequences of interest include [A008457](https://oeis.org/A008457), [A138503](https://oeis.org/A138503). I think this link may be a good resource but (I am pretty sure) the "formula" therein should be labelled as a generating function [A055414](https://oeis.org/A055414).

I suppose it's unlikely that the problem is easier $c>1$ but I figured I would include this thought just in case the problem is somehow solvable for some specific $c$.

**A more general food for thought question**
Does this development get me similar looking things for other dimensions $n$?

Comment: If anyone wanted to chime in about appropriate tags that would help too.

Comment: Wouldn't plugging $\sqrt[2]{R^c}$ into your formula proves your assertion? In fact it seems like the sum converges to $\frac{\pi^4}{384}$ for all real $c\ge 1$

Comment: Ross Millikan's answer (and the subsequent comments) to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2835539/using-circles-to-map-mathbbn-to-mathbbn2/2879046#2879046) may be related.

Comment: @cortek. Yeah. I am not so worried about this assertion. You are referring to "It looks to me like for any whole number c?" Note that $g(x)=\sum^{x}_{n=1}{a_n} \implies g(f(x))=\sum^{f(x)}_{n=1}a_n$. But the implication doesn't go both ways. So the problem may be easier for some specific $c$... but I doubt it.

Comment: I added a bounty with a mistype: should read $\pi^4$ not $\pi/4$. Whoops. It doesn't look like bounty text is editable. More [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20176/there-should-be-a-way-to-edit-bounty-text/29295#29295).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. We can exploit this technique into giving us a form of $\pi^4$. One thing to do with this is get a representation of $\zeta(4)$.

We are interested in interpreting $\sum_{n=1}^x r_8(n)$. One way is to think of it as an approximation of the $8$-dimensional ball which has volume $\pi^4/24$ and the other is to exploit a formula for $r_8(n)$ and examining the asymptotic behavior of $\sum_{n=1}^x r_8(n)$. This is what happens in this [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1k2-basel-pro?rq=1#2329719).

We will need that $\sum_{n=1}^x \sigma_k(x) \approx \frac{\zeta(k+1)} {k+1}x^{k+1}$ to make this very precise we may say that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}{\frac{k+1}{x^{k+1}}\sum_{n=1}^x{\sigma_k(n)}}=\zeta(k+1)$$
I think that this can be seen with just a slight rewriting of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2954097/asymptotic-formula-for-sum-n-leq-x-sigman-knowing-sum-n-leq-x-frac-s).

We have built up all the needed tools I believe:

From equation (12) of this [paper](http://people.math.carleton.ca/~williams/papers/pdf/236.pdf) we can write

$r_8(n)=16\sigma_3(n)-32\sigma_3(n/2)+256\sigma_3(n/4)$

Now equipped with $\sum_{n=1}^x\sigma_3(\frac{n}{a})\approx \frac{\zeta(4)}{4}(\frac{x}{a})^4$

We may write that 
$$\begin{align}
&\frac{\pi^4}{24}x^4 \\
&\approx&\sum_{n=1}^x r_8(n) \\ 
&=&16\sum_{n=1}^x {\sigma_3(n)}
&-32\sum_{n=1}^x {\sigma_3(n/2)}
&+256\sum_{n=1}^x {\sigma_3(n/4)}\\
&\approx &16 \frac{\zeta(4)}{4}x^4
&-32\frac{\zeta(4)}{4}(\frac{x}{2})^4 
&+256 \frac{\zeta(4)}{4}(\frac{x}{4})^4 
\\
&=x^4\zeta(4)\frac{15}{4}
\end{align}$$

So we have that as we let $x$ grow large

$$\frac{\pi^4}{24}x^4 \approx \frac{15}{4}\zeta(4)x^4$$

So then we can conclude that $\zeta(4)=\pi^4/90$

Answer (score 2):

Neat Question! What follows is mostly a long comment.

Define $\tilde{\sigma}_s(n):=\sum_{d|n}(-1)^{d-1}d^s$, an "alternating sum of divisors function." Your sum becomes $\sum_{r=1}^x(-1)^{r+1}\tilde{\sigma}_3(r)$. 
If you now take the classical sum-of-divisors $\sigma_s(n)$, then it's easy to see that $\tilde{\sigma}_s(2k+1)=\sigma_s(2k+1)$ and $\tilde{\sigma}_s(2k)=\sigma_s(2k)-2^{s+1}\sigma_s(k)$.

Your sum is *almost* the famous Ramanujan Eisenstein sum $Q(q):=1+240\sum_{r=1}^\infty\sigma_3(r)q^r=1+240\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{r^3q^r}{1-q^r}$, the difference being your sum is finite and with the caveat that this sum blows up for $|q|=1$. That's unfortunate because for $|q|<1$, there are a slew of identites that $Q$ satisfies, and I'm not sure they will carry over easily in the finite case. It looks like this might be relevant paper, where you'll find a compendium of identities for $\tilde{\sigma}_3(n)$, along with analogous infinite Ramanujan Eisenstein sums:

[Convolution Sums of some functions on divisors -- Hahn](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.04426)

Comment: Thanks! Just a note: $E_4$ in the notation of this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_series)