# Asymptotic formula for $\sum_{n\leq x}\sigma(n)$ knowing $\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}$

Tags: asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, divisor-sum

> Let $\sigma(n):=\sum_{d|n}d$ be the sum of all divisors of $n$. Find the asymptotic formula for $\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}$ and use it to find the one for $\sum_{n\leq x}\sigma(n)$.

Here is my attempt:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}=\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{d|n}\frac{n}{d}
&=\sum_{n\leq x}\sum_{d|n}\frac{1}{d}\\
&=\sum_{d\leq x}\sum_{k\leq \frac{x}{d}}\frac{1}{d}\\
&=\sum_{d\leq x}\frac{1}{d}\sum_{k\leq \frac{x}{d}}1\\
&=\sum_{d\leq x}\frac{1}{d}\left\lfloor{\frac{x}{d}}\right\rfloor
\end{align*}
Since $\left\lfloor\frac{x}{d}\right\rfloor=\frac{x}{d}+O(1)$, we have:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}&=\sum_{d\leq x}\left(\frac{x}{d^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{d}\right)\right)\\
&=x\underbrace{\sum_{d\leq x}\frac{1}{d^2}}_{=\frac{\pi^2}{6}+O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}+\underbrace{O\left(\sum_{d\leq x}\frac{1}{d}\right)}_{=O(\log(x))}\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{6}x+\underbrace{O(1)+O(\log(x))}_{=O(\log(x))}
\end{align*}
Now to estimate $\sum_{n\leq x}\sigma(n)$, I thought about using Abel's summation:
$$\sum_{n\leq x} \frac{\sigma(n)}{n}=\frac{1}{x}\left(\sum_{n\leq x}\sigma(n)\right)+\int_1^x\frac{1}{t^2}\left(\sum_{n\leq t}\sigma(n)\right)dt$$
I suppose that's a reasonable way, exept that I don't know what to do with $\sum_{n\leq t}\sigma(n)$.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use partial summation the other way around: start with $\sum_{n \leq x} \sigma(n)$ and relate it to $x \sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\sigma(n)}{n}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll answer my own question (full credits to @Peter Humphries)

As demonstrated in my first attempt, $\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}x+O(\log x)$. Now the trick is to write $\sigma(n)=\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}\cdot n$ and use Abel's summation:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\leq x}\sigma(n)&=\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}\cdot n\\
&=x\underbrace{\left(\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}\right)}_{=\frac{\pi^2}{6}x+O(\log x)}-\int_1^x\underbrace{\left(\sum_{n\leq t}\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}\right)}_{=\frac{\pi^2}{6}t+O(\log t)}dt\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{6}x^2+O(x\log x)-\frac{\pi^2}{6}\int_1^xt\,dt+O\left(\int_1^x\log (t)dt\right)\\
\end{align*}
Since $\int_1^xt\,dt=\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{1}{2}$ and $\int_1^x\log(t)dt=t\log t-t|_1^x=x\log x-x+1$, we conclude:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\leq x}\sigma(n)&=\frac{\pi^2}{6}x^2+O(x\log x)-\frac{\pi^2}{12}x^2+\underbrace{\frac{\pi^2}{12}+O(x\log x-x+1)}_{O(x\log x)}\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{12}x^2+O(x\log x)
\end{align*}

Comment: I believe using the exact same techniques as above we can arrive at $\sum_{n\le x}\sigma_k(n) \approx \frac{\zeta(k+1) }{k+1}x^{k+1}$. I am struggling to keep track of the error term precisely but that may be a project for another day (or some other interested on-looker).

Comment: I figured out the error term! It should be on the order of $x^k$.
 Hooray! I am providing a link to this [argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2984656/for-what-k-in-mathbbc-do-we-have-lim-x-to-infty-frac1xk1-sum-n).