# Asymptotic behavior $\sum_{n=1}^x\phi_k(n)$, a variant of Euler's Totient function

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, totient-function, divisor-sum

Let $$\phi_k(x)=\sum_{1\le n \le x \\(n,x)=1} n^k$$
What's the asymptotic behavior of 
$$\sum_{n=1}^x\phi_k(n)?$$

According to the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) $\sum^x_{n=1} \phi_0 (n) \approx  \frac{3}{\pi^2}x^2 $. It also appears in page $69$ and $70$ which are $30$ and $31$ of this [pdf](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~hildebr/ant/main2.pdf).

**The possible routes**

**Route 1** (For someone who wants some practice with Abel Summations): There should be an approach which is an analog to the techniques shown here: [sum of the divisor functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2984656/for-what-k-in-mathbbc-do-we-have-lim-x-to-infty-frac1xk1-sum-n) and I think that $\sum_{n=1}^x \frac{\phi_k(n)}{n^{k+1}}$ is always on the order of a linear function. So that might be the place to start.

If no one takes this route I will almost certainly post my own answer in 2 or 3 weeks and ask this community for help verifying my proof. This is the most obvious route for me to take to make progress on this.

**Route 2:** Also it would be particularly interesting to see an argument which isn't an analog of the linked post and which exploits what we already know about the asymptotic behavior of $\sum \sigma_k(n)$ to make claims about $\sum \phi_k(n)$. I am not sure this possible but it may be a route forward.

Comment: [For those of us who like graphs and want to see it to believe it](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gzlq5339am).

Comment: $\sum_{d | m} \mu(d)  \sum_{dn \le m} (dn)^k = ?$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2737492/questions-on-convergence-of-explicit-formulas-for-fx-sum-limits-n-1x-an

Answer (score 0):

Reuns asks: What is $$\sum_{d|m} \mu(d)\sum_{nd\le m} (dn)^k$$

I dunno. Maybe:

$$\sum_{d|m} \mu(d)d^k\sum_{nd\le m} n^k$$

$$\sum_{d|m} \mu(d)d^kf_k(\lfloor m/d \rfloor)$$

Where $f_k(x)=\sum_{n=1}^x n^k $ is a [Faulhaber sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula). This may not be what is being sought though...

Comment: Sorry for my sloppy old comment $\phi_k(n) = \sum_{m \le n, (m,n)=1} m^k$ is a sum of multiplicative functions (related to $\zeta(s)$) because $\sum_{d | n} d^k \phi_k(n/d)=\sum_{d | n} \sum_{m \le n, (m,n)=d} m^k= \sum_{m=1}^n m^k = \sum_{l=0}^{k+1} c_l n^l$ (for some $c_l= c_l(k)$ not depending on $n$) so $\phi_k(n) =\sum_{d | n} \mu(d) \sum_{l=0}^{k+1} c_l (n/d)^l= \sum_{l=0}^{k+1} c_l  \sum_{d | n} \mu(d)(n/d)^l$ and hence $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \phi_k(n)  n^{-s} = \sum_{l=0}^{k+1} c_l\frac{\zeta(s-l)}{\zeta(s)}$$ Looking at the poles shows the possible asymptotic of $\sum_{n \le N}\phi_k(n)$

Comment: Awesome Awesome Awesome! This [looks](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/m4ksx4prz0) good and definitely something I can work with.

Comment: I meant $\phi_k(n) =\sum_{d | n} \mu(d)d^{k} \sum_{l=0}^{k+1} c_l (n/d)^l$ so it is $\sum_l c_l \zeta(s-l)/\zeta(s-k)$

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\phi_k(n)}{n^s}=\frac{1}{\zeta(s-k)}\sum_{l=0}^{k+1}c(k,l)\zeta(s-l)$$

Where $c(k,k+1)=\frac{1}{k+1}, c(k,k)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $c(k, k-l+1) = \frac{B_lk!}{l!(k-l+1)!}$

where $B_k$ is the $k$th Bernoulli number which we define in terms of Stirling numbers of the second kind.

$$B_k=\sum_{m=0}^k \frac{(-1)^mm!}{m+1}S(k,m), \text{ and } S(k,m)=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^{k-j} {k \choose j} j^m$$

$c(a,b)$ are coefficients which we can find in [Faulhaber's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula). In particular, let's consider $k=4$,

$$1^4+2^4+3^4+ \dots x^k \\=c(4,5)x^{5}+c(4,4)x^4+c(4,3)x^3+c(4,2)x^2+c(4,1)x
\\ = \frac{1}{5}x^5+\frac{1}{2}x^4+\frac{1}{3}x^3-\frac{1}{30}x $$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\phi_4(n)}{n^s} = \frac{1}{\zeta(s-4)}\bigg[ \frac{1}{5} \zeta(s-5)+\frac{1}{2}\zeta(s-4)+\frac{1}{3}\zeta(s-3)- \frac{1}{30} \zeta(s-1) \bigg]$$

Here's a [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xkgbfdtdhb) of this lining up! Lovely.

Then we can somehow look at the poles of this to find the asymptotic behavior.

Comment: @reuns. Now equipped with a dirichlet series we can associate with $\phi_4$ is it possible to make any progress on the asympotic behavior of $\sum^x_{n=1}\phi_4(n) $? I suppose the poles mean when $\zeta(s-4)=0$? This seems like it should be as hard as the RH... 
Anyway: I wanted to comment that the approach above works for whole numbered $k$ but in general this techinique won't work arbitrary $k$.